# Link a podspec framework with a framework that's defined in the Podfile

Tags: xcode, firebase, cocoapods

I have some code which is defined in a podspec. Lets call it the **Plugin**. The project imports the Plugin in the Podfile as a development pod.

`pod 'Plugin', :path => 'path/to/podspec'`

The project also depends on Firebase. That's also defined in the Podfile.

`pod "Firebase"`

Now, I would like to be able to access Firebase from inside my Plugin i.e. I would like to be able to call Firebase methods from both my main project and the Plugin.

Is this possible by manually changing the Build Settings in the Pods project?

Background:

The reason I want to do this is because Firebase is distributed as a framework - the source isn't available. When I add a dependency to Firebase in the plugin podspec, there are header not found errors. I've contacted the developers of Firebase and this is a known issue that they won't fix. As a workaround, I downloaded the Firebase frameworks and added them to the podspec using the `vendored_frameworks` command and this works. But it causes all sorts of headaches when I try to import other pods that also depend on Firebase.

Comment: The Firebase team is making progress on improving this situation. Some of Firebase is now open sourced at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk and we're working on a CocoaPods PR that would allow other pods to cleanly depend on Firebase - https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/6811

Comment: That's great! I saw the open source project. Once all the Firebase modules are open source it will make life much easier.